# Transpose in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a dataset

```
2011 A 560

2011 B 349

2012 A 456

2012 B 789
```

Output:

```
      A   B
2011 560 349

2012 456 789
```

I want to this in excel manually and also through vba. any help appreciated.

Comment: A google search for 'transpose in excel' will yield numerous useful results. If you want to do it in VBA, record a macro and look at the code it generates. Although I suspect you don't want to transpose, that looks more like a pivot table operation.

Comment: I am not able to transpose it this way. When i apply paste special its transpose the whole table in rows which is contrary to my expectation.

Comment: how do i do it manually? without vba?

Comment: Give your data column headers and create a pivot table out of it.

Comment: Can anyone (Ripster) please give me the excact code. I understood the code that @Ripster wrote but i am not able to do the opposite.  I have been stuck with this for the past 3 hours. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

IFF that's what your dataset looks like.

Select all of your data and insert a pivot table.
Set your rows to the first column (the one that has the year)
Set your columns to the the second column (the one that has A or B)
Set your values as the average of the third column (the one that has the numbers)

Answer (score 0):

First give your data headers

[image: data with headers]

Create a pivot table out of your data

```
Sub PivotData()
    Dim PivotSource As Range
    Dim PivotName As String
    Dim PivotDest As Range


    PivotName = "PivotTable1"
    Set PivotSource = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
    Set PivotDest = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

    'Select the sheet containing data
    Sheets(PivotSource.Parent.Name).Select

    'Create a pivot cache out of the data
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                                      SourceData:=PivotSource, _
                                      Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
                                      TableDestination:=PivotDest, _
                                      TableName:=PivotName, _
                                      DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14

    'Select the destination Sheet
    Sheets(PivotDest.Parent.Name).Select

    'Create the pivot table
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(PivotName)
        .PivotFields("Year").Orientation = xlRowField
        .PivotFields("Year").Position = 1
        .AddDataField .PivotFields("Value"), "Sum of Value", xlSum
        .PivotFields("Type").Orientation = xlColumnField
        .PivotFields("Type").Position = 1
        .RowGrand = False
        .ColumnGrand = False
    End With

    'Convert the pivot table to a range
    Cells.Copy
    Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                       Operation:=xlNone, _
                       SkipBlanks:=False, _
                       Transpose:=False

    'Remove the pivot table header
    Rows(1).Delete
    Range("A1").ClearContents

    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Result:

[image: Pivoted Data]